# Variable no definida

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter, variables

Soy nuevo usando el módulo de python tkinter y no se muy bien como funcionan las cosas así que si alguien me pudiera explicar potque pasa esto agradezco de atemano:

Cuando creo esta función me aparece como si la variable "entryw1_1 no estuviera definida cuando si lo está:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM, LEFT
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import Toplevel, messagebox
import time
from typing import get_args




mainwindow = tk.Tk()
mainwindow.title('Automeet 0.2')
mainwindow.configure(background='grey')
mainwindow.geometry('650x300')

ventana1 = 0
ventana2 = 0
ventana3 = 0
ventana4 = 0
ventana5 = 0
ventana6 = 0
ventana7 = 0

def createWindow1():
    global x
    x = 1
    global ventana1
    if ventana1 < 1:
        window1 = tk.Toplevel()
        window1.geometry('300x300')

        labelw1_1 = tk.Label(window1, text='Hora de ejecución:')
        labelw1_1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        entryw1_1 = tk.Entry(window1)
        entryw1_1.grid(column=1, row=0)

        labelw1_2 = tk.Label(window1, text='Minutos de ejecución:')
        labelw1_2.grid(column=0, row=1)
        entryw1_2 = tk.Entry(window1)
        entryw1_2.grid(column=1, row=1)

        labelw1_3 = tk.Label(window1, text='Link del meet:')
        labelw1_3.grid(column=0, row=2)
        entryw1_3 = tk.Entry(window1)
        entryw1_3.grid(column=1, row=2)

        def getvar():
            global hour
            global x
            global entryw1_1
            if x == 1:
                hour = entryw1_1.get()

        buttonw1_entry = tk.Button(window1)
        buttonw1_entry.grid(column=3, row=4, text='cerrar', command=getvar)

        ventana1 = 1
def createWindow2():
    if ventana2 < 1:
        window2 = tk.Toplevel()
def createWindow3():
    if ventana3 < 1:
        window3 = tk.Toplevel()
def createWindow4():
    if ventana4 < 1:
        window4 = tk.Toplevel()
def createWindow5():
    if ventana5 < 1:
        window5 = tk.Toplevel()
def createWindow6():
    if ventana6 < 1:
        window6 = tk.Toplevel()
def createWindow7():
    if ventana7 < 1:
        window7 = tk.Toplevel()

titlefont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size='20', weight=font.BOLD)

label1 = tk.Label(mainwindow, text='Bienvenido a AutoMeet', bg='white')
label1['font'] = titlefont
label1.pack()

Cl1_button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='Configurar Clase 1', command=createWindow1,)
Cl1_button.pack() 

Cl2_button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='Configurar Clase 2', command=createWindow2,)
Cl2_button.pack()

Cl3_button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='Configurar Clase 3', command=createWindow3,)
Cl3_button.pack()

Cl4_button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='Configurar Clase 4', command=createWindow4,)
Cl4_button.pack()

Cl5_button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='Configurar Clase 5', command=createWindow5,)
Cl5_button.pack()

Cl6_button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='Configurar Clase 6', command=createWindow6,)
Cl6_button.pack()

Cl7_button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='Configurar Clase 7', command=createWindow7,)
Cl7_button.pack()
mainwindow.mainloop()
```

El error es el siguiente: ***"entryw1_1" is not definedPylance(reportUndefinedVariable)***

¿Como hago para que desaparezca el error?

El problema es que la variable  de entryw1_1 es en realidad el espacio para introducir la variable pero está definida encima y además declarada dentro de la variable "getvar()" con un global así que si que debería reconocerla.

Comment: Dejar el codigo completo puede hacer mas sencilla la tarea de ayudarte con tu problema.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con el código completo

Comment: No tengo tiempo de probarlo ahora, pero diría que justamente el problema está en que usas global en la función interna, pero no en la externa, entonces terminas haciendo referencia a distintas variables. Agrega global antes de asignarla en `createWindow1()` o quita el global de `getvar()`.

Comment: Si, ya está. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta referir a la variable como global en la función interna ya que así se considera una variable distinta que no está definida